# Using _bin_deployableAssemblies with Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio, assemblies, visual-studio-2012, webdeploy

With Visual Studio 2010 I used the _bin_deployableAssemblies folder to include third party assemblies which should be included in the bin folder on build and web deploy.
It's about those third party assemblies which are needed for the website, but you don't want to reference them.
This worked awesome...

Now with Visual Studio 2012 it stopped working... Well, a part of it stopped working.
When I build, the contents of the _bin_deployableAssemblies folder are copied to the bin folder.
But when I execute webdeploy, for instance to my local disk, those files are not published to the output folder's bin folder.

I'm using this in my .csproj file:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <OnAfterCopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackage>
    __MoveFilesFromUmbracoSubdirsToBinPackageTemp
  </OnAfterCopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackage>
</PropertyGroup>
<Target Name="_CopyBinDeployableAssemblies" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\_bin_deployableAssemblies')">
  <CreateItem Include="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\_bin_deployableAssemblies\**\*.*" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\_bin_deployableAssemblies')" Exclude="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\_bin_deployableAssemblies\**\.svn\**\*">
    <Output ItemName="_binDeployableAssemblies" TaskParameter="Include" />
  </CreateItem>
  <Copy SourceFiles="@(_binDeployableAssemblies)" DestinationFolder="$(OutDir)" SkipUnchangedFiles="true" Retries="$(CopyRetryCount)" RetryDelayMilliseconds="$(CopyRetryDelayMilliseconds)" />
</Target>
<Target Name="__MoveFilesFromUmbracoSubdirsToBinPackageTemp">
  <Message Text="Moving files from bin\umbraco\ and bin\umbraco plugins\ to bin\" Importance="high" />
  <CreateItem Include="$(_PackageTempDir)\bin\umbraco\*.*;$(_PackageTempDir)\bin\umbraco plugins\*.*">
    <Output ItemName="_umbracoItems" TaskParameter="Include" />
  </CreateItem>
  <Move SourceFiles="@(_umbracoItems)" DestinationFolder="$(_PackageTempDir)\bin" />
  <Message Text="Removing bin\umbraco\ and bin\umbraco plugins\ folders" Importance="high" />
  <RemoveDir Directories="$(_PackageTempDir)\bin\umbraco;$(_PackageTempDir)\bin\umbraco plugins" />
</Target>
```

Could anyone help me out how I get those assemblies in the ouput folder's bin folder?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to Alexey I found the solution to my problem, this is what I'm using now in my .csproj file to support copying third party assemblies for Filesystem- and Webdeploy:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <AvailableItemName Include="ThirdPartyAssemblies">
        <Visible>false</Visible>
    </AvailableItemName>
</ItemGroup>
<Target Name="AfterBuild">
    <Message Text="Build | Copying third party assemblies to output folder ($(OutputPath))" Importance="high" />
    <Copy DestinationFolder="$(OutputPath)" SourceFiles="@(ThirdPartyAssemblies)" SkipUnchangedFiles="true" />
</Target>
<Target Name="CopyBinFiles" AfterTargets="CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackage" BeforeTargets="MSDeployPublish">
    <Message Text="Deploy | Copying third party assemblies to output folder ($(_PackageTempDir)\bin\)" Importance="high" />
    <Copy DestinationFolder="$(_PackageTempDir)\bin\" SourceFiles="@(ThirdPartyAssemblies)" SkipUnchangedFiles="true" />
</Target>
```

From: [MSBuild targets and Visual Studio 2012 issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12520115/msbuild-targets-and-visual-studio-2012-issues/12579589#12579589)

Answer (score -2):

Assuming you have **Only files needed to run this application** set in project properties, make sure that the files are included in the project and that their Build Action is Content.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee942158.aspx#why_dont_all_files_get_deployed

Comment: It might if in the process of converting the project to 2012 or for some other reason the files copied to the bin folder are no longer included in the project.  The criteria I list are the ones that determine in VS 2012 whether files will be copied to the output bin folder.

Comment: The MsBuild target(s) I posted should take care of the copying process, at least it did in VS2010. So my question is; what has changed in VS2012 and how can I resolve it.

Comment: There seems to be a change affecting OnAfterCopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackage; there's another SO post that seems to be related -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12520115/msbuild-targets-and-visual-studio-2012-issues -- I've asked someone who knows more about it than I do.

Comment: Yes I created that topic too, after I tried other ways than mentioned in my TS to include third party assemblies with Webdeploy.
I'm looking forward to a reply from 'the person who knows more about it than you do' ;-)