# Web deployment failing due to file in use

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-deployment, webdeploy, log4net-appender

I'm using Microsoft's Web Deploy Remote Agent service to allow me to easily publish code to the server from within Visual Studio.

The web site I am deploying is using log4net to log messages to log files, and every time I try to deploy a new version of the code, I get this error in Visual Studio stating that the current log4net log file is in use:

> An error occurred when the request was processed on the remote
>   computer. The file 'Web.log' is in use.
>
> The process cannot access 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Logs\Web.log' because it
>   is being used by another process.

I can solve this by going onto the server and doing an `iisreset` before publishing... but that is kind of defeating the point of 'easy' publishing from Visual Studio :)

Is there some way I can get the publish task to issue an iisreset automatically, or some other way I can work round this?

Comment: Is this your log4Net log file?

Comment: @Tommy Yes, sorry, I should make that clearer :)

Comment: I am wondering if you could tie into the Application_End event in your global.asax and call the shutdown option for log4Net.  This should free up the lock on the file.  I have not had to do this, thus not posted as an answer, but there are a few SO questions and other items related to shutting down the logging service for various other reasons.

Comment: @Tommy Tried it, but it didn't work. Application_End event doesn't seem to get called when publishing :(

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I kept poking around and found some tidbits around the file being locked in a few other forums.  Have you tried adding

```
<lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
```

To your `<appender>` element in the web.config file?  From the [Apache docs](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/?topic=html/T_log4net_Appender_FileAppender_MinimalLock.htm)

> Opens the file once for each AcquireLock/ReleaseLock cycle,
>   thus holding the lock for the minimal amount of time. This method of
>   locking is considerably slower than FileAppender.ExclusiveLock but
>   allows other processes to move/delete the log file whilst logging
>   continues.

As far as the performance considerations, I suppose you would need to test if this will affect you or not as I am assuming it really depends on how often you are writing to the log file as to how much this will impact performance.  I can't believe that getting/releasing a lock could take *all* that much time though.

Answer (score 6):

There is a [MSDEPLOY provider called `recycleApp`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee522997%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) which is used exactly for this. You can include this in your deployment manifest.

Another option is to use `ignoreOnErrors` flag which will skip the file in use and continue with the deployment.

Comment: Can you give some information on recycleApp and how to actually include this? I don't see any options in Visual Studio, same for ignoreOnErrors flag

Comment: You could run this command manually as a pre-deploy step or automated using a VS deployment step - check out [`AfterTargets="CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackage"`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12579589). There isn't yet an option in VS to tell it to recycle the app - only file + SQL publish options.